# Display Int value in text box swift from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have this code in swift 2 to get the Int phone no from Parse and display in a text box

```
        if (PFUser.currentUser()!["phoneNumber"] !== nil)
    {
        mobile.text = String(PFUser.currentUser()!["phoneNumber"] as? Int)
    }
```

But it shows it as `Optional(XXXXXXXXXX)` ...but i just want the it without Optional wrapping like `XXXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use optional chaining and optional binding

```
if let phoneNumber = PFUser.currentUser()?["phoneNumber"] as? Int {
    mobile.text = String(phoneNumber)
}
```